# Does it make sense to re-open a question and immediately re-close it to mark it as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question was fueled by below linked question. The idea behind this question, namely re-opening poorly posed closed questions and mark them as dupe instead, may be important as a general issue, given that dupes are not only allowed, but [may even be desirable in the SE network](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/);

The question [Why do we fear the night?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56185/why-do-we-fear-more-in-the-night)
was closed as being off topic. I voted for closure too, probably due to the kind of awkward way the question was asked.

After the question [Why are fearful stimuli more powerful at night?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55700/why-are-fearful-stimuli-more-powerful-at-night/56797#56797) was answered, OP of the former [Why do we fear the night?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56185/why-do-we-fear-more-in-the-night) question commented that it also answered their closed question.

Now - given that the answered question is very well received and that, in retrospect, OP of the closed question was asking the same thing, I propose to re-open the closed question and mark it as dupe and link the now answered question to it. I edited the closed question to improve the English use.

Comment: This sort of thing is probably more easily dealt with by flagging for mod attention. If you wanted to reopen, and keep open, meta is indeed best (since mods try to avoid going against the community consensus when something was closed for valid reasons). But since you want to reopen and close for another reason, flags are simpler.

Comment: Please open a flag for such cases. I re-opened the unanswered question and closed it as a duplicate of the answered.

Comment: @terdon will use flags the next time. I just thought it could be interesting for other users too.

Comment: @Chris - dito for the flags

Comment: @Chris - I think this might be of broader interest - could you write an answer that you indeed marked a closed question as a  dupe? I think it's better for a site to refer potential interested folks coming across our site to be directed to a similar question than only reading 'closed'. Having an accepted answer on this meta post may aid in this

Comment: You mean a comment on the closed question? Sure, I can do that.

Comment: @Chris - I mean an answer to this question. If you like :-)

Comment: I can't answer closed questions.

Comment: @Chris - No, I meant answering this question using your comment as a guideline :-) As in, "*Yes, closed, unanswered questions can be re-opened and re-closed as a duplicate of the answered question*" or the likes

Comment: Ah, now I have it. Sorry, too much work besides answering here :-) Later...